# Is there an algebraic like tool that can reduce your code down to something efficient?

Tags: javascript

For instance, I am working through http://eloquentjavascript.net's exercise, and one of the tutorials was to create the output:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

the answer given was :

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

And my answer was:

```
var tile = "#";
var piece = "";
var switche = false;
var columns = prompt("enter number of columns","");
var rows = prompt("enter number of rows","");

var lastPiece = "blank";

for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
{

    if (lastPiece == "#") 
    {
        piece += tile;
        lastPiece = "blank";
    }

    else if (lastPiece == "blank") 
    {
        piece += " ";
        lastPiece = "#";
    }
 var row1 = piece; 
}

var lastPiece = "#";
var piece = "";

for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) 
{

    if (lastPiece == "#") 
    {

        piece += tile;
        lastPiece = "blank";
    }

    else if (lastPiece == "blank") 
    {
        piece += " ";
        lastPiece = "#";
    }
var row2 = piece;

}

for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) 
{
if (!switche){
    document.write('&nbsp;'+ row1 + '<br>');
    switche = true;}
    else if(switche){
    document.write('&nbsp;' + row2 + '<br>');
    switche = false;}
}
```

I am not experienced but I can already see that there will be a lot of me writing unnecessary code in the future. Is there some good methodology to prevent that or a tool?

Comment: Your own brain is the best tool for this job!

Comment: Pick up a book on refactoring... The question is probably too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Un?)fortenately there's no tools available for optimizing some arbitrary JS code, your brain is all what you really need (as already said by Greg Hewgill).

Just as a nit-pick, below is a code, which should be even more efficient, than the given answer to your exercise.

```js
var line = ' # # # #',
    n,
    str = '';
for (n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
     str += ((n % 2 === 0) ? line : line.trim()) + '\n';
}
console.log(str); // Could be also put as element.innerHTML when replacing \n with <br> and replacing the leading space in line with &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by efficient I suppose. Clearly just printing the output is the "fastest" you'll ever make this:

console.log(" # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #\n # # # #\n# # # #") // nothing will beat this for speed.

However, you can alternatively use a different meaning for efficient: how much space the program takes up. Ideally we'd like it to take up less space than the output. The program above, while very fast, takes up 13 extra characters than the output (so why wouldn't you just store the output instead?). If we tweak it slightly:

a=" # # # #\n# # # #\n";
console.log([,,,,,].join(a))

Now, we've saved ourselves a whole 16 characters from the original output size. It is of course slower however than our original "just print the answer" solution.

It's "very hard" for a computer to always be able to figure out our top solution. However, the computer can optimize it to that point sometimes, and will do so without changing your actual code (under the hood).